# Restrict direct access to subdomain using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The objective is to restrict any direct access to subdomain (addon.example.com) or urls under it (addon.example.com/anyurl). Should   to direct to a 404 page.

what is required is :

```
addon.example.com --> example.com/404.html 
addon.example.com/anyurl --> example.com/404.html 
example.com/anyurl --> example.com/anyurl
```

I'm using the following code in the .htaccess file in the subdomain (addon domain folder root ) directory.

It works with 404 as intended, in case the request is addon.example.com
But still directs without 404 if the request is  addon.example.com/anyurl

Appreciate any alternate or tweaks to code :)

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?addon\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/404.php [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Why have a subdomain in the first place when everything on it is 404? Just *don't serve* the subdomain on that particular web server.

Comment: The subdomain is an addon domain (cpanel)  in the hosting account. There is a direct access to the subdomain , for example, thru addon.com. The objective is to avoid duplicate urls getting indexed in search results (like addon.example.com/some_url  & addon.com/some_url , both are the same content )

Answer (score 0):

This is what I selected to solve the problem. It gives what is expected...

```
addon.example.com --> example.com/404.html 
addon.example.com/anyurl --> example.com/404.html 
example.com/anyurl --> example.com/anyurl
addon.com/anyurl --> addon.com/anyurl
```

.htaccess code used in the root directory of the addon domain

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !addon\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon\.example\.com$
RewriteRule [addon]?(.*) http://example.com/404.html$1 [R=404,L]
```

This comes handy if you are hosting many domains in cpanel as addon domains, and wants to avoid the addon appearing as a subdomain of the primary domain. Good for SEO as well as if you want to keep each addons appearing as no way related in the urls.

Still appreciate anyone sharing improvements/alternat/efficient .htaccess codes for this problem.